# Вопросительный знак ПОСЛЕ многоточия

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, сохраняется ли вопросительный – и, следовательно, восклицательный – знак в таком случает, как у меня? То есть какое предложение верно?

`1.1. Это, согласен, может, был и Том-кот. А кстати, не думаете ли вы, что это был...?`

`1.2. Это, согласен, может, был и Том-кот. А кстати, не думаете ли вы, что это был...`

`2.1. У вас есть мандари...?`

`2.2. У вас есть мандари...`

Comment: Только есть такое — `?..`.

Comment: Нет. У меня само предложение (или слово) не закончено.

Comment: После многоточия никакие знаки не ставятся. Придётся опустить.

Comment: Это суперплохо-с.